# Standard way for getting Zulu timestamps in Python

Tags: python-3.x, time

Building a REST python client for a server that expects timestamps to be passed in this format:

`2018-05-17T06:57:16.300Z`

When writing clients for this server, it is easy to get this kind of timestamp in both Java (serializing an `Instant` with Jackson) and Javascript (using `new Date().toISOString()`).

However, I couldn't find a standard way of getting this sort of timestamp in Python using the standard library or the common packages for handling time (Arrow, Pendulum).

All the solutions I found online required manually defining the string format, or (even worse) doing string manipulations to add the `Z` at the end of the timestamp and put the `T` in place.

So - is there a standard way of getting current UTC time with the `Z` notation in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. Using Pendulum, one can do the following:

```
pendulum.now(pendulum.UTC).to_iso8601_string()
```